# Graph Api query friends address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

Is it possible to query the current address of my friends using Graph Api 2.2 (no Fql)?

I have already tried this

```
/me?fields=friends{address}
```

but it just returned the ids of my friends but not their address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. There is no such field as `address`

   See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields
2. You can't query for friends info anymore, because all `friends_*`permissions have been deprecated with Graph API v2.0

   See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: 1. The Graph API Explorer suggested the field 'address' thats why I've tried it

Comment: 2. So you mean what I'm trying to do is not possible at all?

Comment: This has just destroyed my whole project.. thank you anyway :D